# Answer external call from Salesforce softphone

Tags: opencti

I am working on development of a sales force CTI Adapter integration with ViciDial.

Suppose a calls lands on the agents extension on vici dial. I want to pick this call from Salesforce Softphone.

How can i update the Softphone UI when there us a call landing on Vicidial.

Vici Dial call a URL to notify an incoming call.

Now my issue is i want to store call logs of these incoming calls. So on what Salesforce objects should i create a Push topic & fire SOQL query so that my soft phone UI is updated and also a call records are also created on the sales force database.

Thanks in advance
Shubhen

Comment: hi @shubhen, were you able to find an answer for this?